# Nikon D7000 on Auto always flashes

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000

When my Nikon D7000 is on auto it always flashes, even outside in full daylight, - is that normal, and if so, what good does the flash do in sunlight?
Terry

Answer (score 1):

On your D7000 dial where you set Auto, the symbol on the dial right beside Auto is a little lightning bolt with a line through it.  You can use it in that position, which means still Auto, but the Flash is always turned off (even when otherwise needed). See your camera manual.

Or, you could learn to use A, S, P, or M mode, and then in those modes, the flash will only flash if you open it's door first.  In Auto, you also have Auto ISO, Auto White Balance, auto everything, but in A, S, P, or M, you only have whatever you set (which could still be auto stuff if desired).  P mode with Auto ISO on and Auto White Balance on won't be much different than Auto (except the flash only flashes when you open its door first), but you still have choices about controlling things.

Fill flash in bright sun is often a very good thing.  Otherwise, pictures of people can have dark harsh shadows on the face, and the flash can help that greatly if still in flash range, not too far.  Eight or ten feet is getting pretty to be about the limit for the little internal flash.

Answer (score 0):

As per the manual:
http://www.nikonsupport.eu/europe/Manuals/D7000/D7000_En_05.pdf

On page 145 :

> **AUTO (auto flash):** When lighting is poor or subject is back lit, flash pops up automatically  when shutter-release button is pressed
>   halfway and fires as required.

So it is not normal that your flash comes up always.

Are you sure it is in auto mode for flash, and not for the camera itself?

Perhaps your camera is set to auto-mode, but the flash is set to something like "fill-flash" which can appear always.